# How to save subquery result?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, subquery, entity-framework-6

I have such query:

```
var result = from tsr in db.tsr
where tsr.SomeId = x
where tsr.Sequence > ((from tsr2 in db.tsr where tsr2.SomeId = y where tsr2.FitId = tsr.FitId select tsr2.Sequence)).FirstOrDefault()
select new MyClass()
{
   Properties = tsr.properties // (simplicified)
}
```

I wonder how to select `tsr2.Sequence` value into my `NewClass` object?

Answer (score 0):

```
select new MyClass(){

MyClass.Property1 = tsr.Sequence.PropertyX,
MyClass.Property2 = tsr.Sequence.PropertyY,
MyClass.Property3 = tsr.Sequence.PropertyZ,
......
}
```

you can select and assign properties one by one. And be sure to your MyClass object properties is public

Comment: I need to select tsr2.Sequence, not tsr(1)

Comment: but you just use tsr2 in query operation , you cant reach tsr2.Properties like that. maybe you can use join keyword or you can create relation with tsr and tsr2 and you can directly access tsr2 on tsr , after that you can access the properties with : tsr.tsr2.SomePropertyX.